# How to align plots with facet_wrap2 and patchwork?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork, ggh4x

I am having difficulty aligning my grid figure correctly when I have removed the repeating tick labels on the y-axis while combining other facet wraps with different length tick labels in patchwork. I have prepared an example to demonstrate the problem I am currently having.

```r
library(ggh4x, warn.conflicts = F)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: ggplot2
library(ggplot2, warn.conflicts = F)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(patchwork, warn.conflicts = F)

# trim_blank is working
trimmed_1 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = factor(class)) %>%
  filter(class == c("2seater", "compact", "midsize")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy * 1000)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap2(vars(class), axes = "x", remove_labels = "all", trim_blank = T)

# trim_blank is not working
untrimmed_1 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = factor(class)) %>%
  filter(class == c("2seater", "compact", "midsize")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy * 1000)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap2(vars(class), axes = "all", remove_labels = "all", trim_blank = T)


# trim_blank is working
trimmed_2 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = factor(cyl)) %>%
  filter(class == c("4", "6", "8")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, log(cty))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap2(vars(cyl), axes = "x", remove_labels = "all", trim_blank = T)

# trim_blank is not working
untrimmed_2 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = factor(cyl)) %>%
  filter(class == c("4", "6", "8")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, log(cty))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap2(vars(cyl), axes = "all", remove_labels = "all", trim_blank = T)

(trimmed_1 / trimmed_2) # plots are aligned
```

[image]

```r
(untrimmed_1 / untrimmed_2) # plots are not horizontally aligned
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-24 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you expect from `trim_blank`. According to the docs

> When TRUE (default), does not draw rows and columns containing no panels. When FALSE, the nrow and ncol arguments are taken literally, even when there are more than needed to fit all panels.

But to fix your issue with the alignment you can use `ggplot2::facet_wrap` instead of `ggh4x::facet_wrap2` which in `ggplot2 3.5.0` gained some of the functionalities from `ggh4x`, i.e. `facet_wrap` now has an `axes=` and an `axis.labels=` argument. And as a side-effect works fine when aligning the plots using `patchwork`:

```r
library(ggplot2, warn.conflicts = F)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(patchwork, warn.conflicts = F)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.0'
packageVersion("patchwork")
#> [1] '1.2.0'

untrimmed_1 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = factor(class)) %>%
  filter(class == c("2seater", "compact", "midsize")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy * 1000)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(class), axes = "all", axis.labels = "all_x")

untrimmed_2 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = factor(cyl)) %>%
  filter(class == c("4", "6", "8")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, log(cty))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cyl), axes = "all", axis.labels = "all_x")

untrimmed_1 / untrimmed_2 # plots are aligned
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan! This is already the solution for the issue. I think that prior to this update, this was only possible using '''ggh4x::facet_wrap2'''.